# What does the Neumann boundary condition imply for the electric flux lines?

Tags: electrostatics, boundary-conditions

If I prescribe a Neumann boundary condition in an electrostatic problem, that means that I am prescribing a surface charge density, and in the way I understand it that means that the electric flux lines have to be normal to this surface. Is this right?

Comment: Having Neumann boundary condition means that on a surface you prescribe the normal component of the gradient $\mathbf{E}=\textrm{grad}\phi$ of the potential function $\phi$, that is $E_n=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial n}$ is given. It does not mean that the tangential component of $E_t= \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t}$ is zero that is the field is orthogonal $\mathbf{E}$ to the surface.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If we have a homogenous Neumann boundary condition, will this mean that the field lines are normal to the surface?

Answer (score 2):

*[Neumann boundary conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_boundary_condition)* is a general mathematical term for the conditions on the derivatives of a function. It is applicable in this context in the sense that we are talking about the Laplace/Poisson equation for the electric potential, $\varphi$, although the conditions are actually on the electric field strength, $\mathbf{E}=-\nabla\cdot\varphi$, and the electric displacement field $\mathbf{D}$ ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields)):
$$\mathbf{n}_{12}\times (\mathbf{E}_2 - \mathbf{E}_1) = 0,\\
\mathbf{n}_{12}\cdot (\mathbf{D}_2 - \mathbf{D}_1) = \sigma_s,$$
where $\mathbf{n}_{12}$ is the normal to the surface. The first condition impose continuity of the component of the electric field parallel to the surface, whereas the second means that its normal component $\mathbf{E}_i = \mathbf{D}_i/\epsilon_i$ changes by a jump. Thus, the direction of the electric field lines, which is the direction of $\mathbf{E}$ changes.

*Note that the electric field lines do not have to be perpendicular to the surface!* This is the case for metals, since the electric field inside a metal should be zero ($\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{D} = 0$), but not for dielectrics.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just to check if I understand it correctly, a Neumann boundary condition on a surface defined by $\mathbf{n_{12}}$ leads to the field lines having a change in their direction (there is a jump in the normal component) when crossing the surface?

Comment: This is correct. Note that this jump occurs even if the surface charge density is zero, but the dielectric constant is different on the two sides (for a metal one can formally take $\epsilon=\infty$).